# How to make tesseract recognize more exactly with small image?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I'm having an image, is a string of numbers and some alphabet, then i use tesseract to recognize them, but it gave a wrong result, how to fix this?

Here is image:

[image: Sample image]

Here is my code:

```
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cropped_frame, config='--psm 10 -c page_separator=""')        
print(text)
```

The result is `8008864`

Comment: pls try to resize it up. `from PIL import Image img=Image.open(image_file_name)
img=img.resize((img.size[0]*30,img.size[1]*30))` and then `text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='--psm 10 -c page_separator=""')        
print(text)` , and will result in `BO09864`

Comment: How about it's cropped image?

Comment: What is recieve is image more blur, and result is ````B0O0S664````

Comment: pls note platform does matter for pytesseract. I tried on mac and google colab, and getting the expected result "BO09864". these are versions I tried on :macOS-  ('4.1.1') and google colab: '4.0.0-beta.1' . The picture I took is a screen snap of the image you have here in your question.

Comment: I'm using windows 10, and run ````tesseract.exe --version```` it show some informations like this: ````tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20201127
 leptonica-1.78.0
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.3) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0
 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found FMA
 Found SSE
 Found libarchive 3.3.2 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.2.3 bz2lib/1.0.6 liblz4/1.7.5
 Found libcurl/7.59.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2o (WinSSL) zlib/1.2.11 WinIDN libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.31.0````